# Python math.pow function needs float()

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the value of 10^r in python.  I started with `pow(10, r)`, but I was told that I had a TypeError and needed a float.  I tried using `(10**r)` and `pow(10, float(r))`, but nothing is working.  In the first, I got a "TypeError - unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'."  In the second, I was told that `float()` needed a string or number argument.  Any tips will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: do you have "from math import pow" in your code? what type is 'r'? did you define 'r' variable at all?

Comment: Is it the `r` that's causing the issue, or the `10`?

Comment: I have `from math import floor, pow`.  r is defined as `def generateNumber(r):`.

Comment: @cHao It is `r`.  It is somehow undefined - see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your first argument, but your second. Check out what `r` is assigned to (In a pinch, add `print(repr(r))` just before the `pow` line. Most likely, you assigned it by accident to a value you don't want - you wanted to write

```
r = input()
```

, which calls the `input` function, but you wrote

```
r = input
```

which just creates an alias for `input` named `r`.

Comment: Ah. It is somehow initialize to `<built-in function input>`.  I guess I need to look at the caller.

Comment: @user2509848 See the updated answer for what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I had actually returned `input` instead if `diff` in a previous method, so in effect, I had written r = input.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From the error, it seems that `r` is assigned to a function by mistake. I'm guessing you're calling your function with something like this: `generateNumber(float)`. Or the argument is one of your own functions, but you forgot to add parentheses: `generateNumber(myOwnFunction)` instead of the correct `generateNumber(myOwnFunction())`.

Answer (score 1):

It works easily like this:

```
>>> from math import pow
>>> r = 2.3     # here it is defined as a float
>>> pow(10,r)
199.52623149688787
>>> 10**r
199.52623149688787
```

also you can check the type:

```
>>> isinstance(r,float)
True
```

if you do not know the type use this:

```
>>> type(r)
<type 'float'>
```